# Getting google 404 error with google app engine and godaddy domain

Tags: google-app-engine, domain-name

I am getting 404 error after configuring godaddy domain vbhujangarao.com to app engine application.I have configured the following in godaddy domain settings page

A record with host @ with IP 216.239.32.21 and

CNAME record with host www to ghs.googlehosted.com 

 added forwarding to http://www.vbhujangarao.com in godaddy. 

Added this www.vbhujangarao.com in https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings page.

can anyone let me know the mistake i am doing it here?

Comment: Don't use the godaddy tag. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288200/kill-the-godaddy-tag-with-fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, I have an similar configuration but with BlueHost, but I'm sure that it should work with godaddy.

Just check the conf in de goolgle cloud console should be like this:

```
Custom domain names SSL support Record type  Data            Alias  
www.vbhujangarao.com    none    CNAME     ghs.googlehosted.com  www
```

You can find the configuration page in 
https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains? 
in the sheet "Custom Domains"

And in your cname configuration:

```
*www        ghs.googlehosted.com*
```

The only diffrerence that I notice with my configuration is taht I don't have the record with @ and the IP. Try to remove it.

Sorry I can't help more. Is your site accesible without the custom domain?

Comment: Thanks Pere Martra .I have not done any configuration changes in google cloud console other than just adding custom domain.Where do we need to configure this in google cloud console. I have tried removing the @ record with IP but no use.

Comment: Do I need to signup for google apps or anything with the domain name?

Comment: Thanks It worked after adding configuration in google cloud console.There was a Add button in custom domain page in cloud console but clicking on this not showing up anything message so I was confused.